# recursion causing mutableData.setValue() causing the same activity to be produced in backstack?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Edit: 23/10/2016**:  This is *not solved* and I'm still looking for an answer. I am going to rewrite this question to make it clearer as I now know what's causing this problem.

---

**Edit: 26/10/2016: SOMETHING FOUND:** While trying to find the problem, I got a bug that helped me find something .It turns out if I have this in my Firebase database:

```
Campaigns{
   UNQ_KEY: 1 //This is being set in the transaction
}
```

**Rather than** this:

```
Campaigns{
   UNQ_KEY:{
    count: 1 //this is being set in the transaction
  }
}
```

**The problem *doesn't happen***.

So, in conclusion, it's probably a recursion error.

---

I have this Firebase transaction:

```
database.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Long preUserIncrementedInt = Long.parseLong(b.getText().toString());
            Long userIncrementedInt = ++preUserIncrementedInt;
            mutableData.child("users").child(getUid()).child("count").setValue(userIncrementedInt);
            Long preIncrementedTotalCount = mutableData.child("count").getValue(Long.class);
            Long incrementedTotalCount = ++preIncrementedTotalCount;
            mutableData.child("count").setValue(incrementedTotalCount);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (databaseError != null)
                Log.wtf(TAG,databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

**This line:**

```
mutableData.child("users").child(getUid()).child("count").setValue(userIncrementedInt);
```

**and this one:**

```
mutableData.child("count").setValue(incrementedTotalCount);
```

When I run the transaction, the same activity gets created again and opens. When I click the back button, it goes to the previous activity in the backstack. BUT, the previous activity in the backstack is the same activity itself. Like this:

[image]

Each time I click the button, a new activity (activity with the problem) is produced in the backstack.

To show you how it looks like, here's a GIF:

[image: GIF]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the Activity code?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai sure. Just wanted to make sure it wasn't a tiny error so I didn't provide the whole code. Just give me a sec

Comment: @AbAppletic does it give any error stacktrace ? or it just restart without complaining about anything? can you try catching Exception and print it ? maybe is some error that isn't in those 3

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque nothing. Just restarts.

Comment: Full code: http://paste.ofcode.org/JF7YYwFrbEJ7pZwDzKJLGN

Comment: Can you wrap the code with a Exception catch and print the stacktrace, below the null pointer

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque I'll try

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque no stack trace

Comment: use Log.d inside the Transaction.Result to see if it gets printed (at the beggining and before the return)

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque you want me to log Transaction.Result?

Comment: Or just do a test logging to see if the statement gets executed?

Comment: exactly, just to see if the statement get executed

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque They're both getting executed.

Comment: This is very weird. I've never seen such a bug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124668/discussion-between-abappletic-and-ivan-alburquerque).

Comment: @AbAppletic in your sample code, you don't print out the Exception traces when it crashes. Make sure you `e.printStackTrace();` in everything!

Comment: I'll add that; but I'd like to inform you that **the data saves successfully to the database** :)

Comment: @AbAppletic what happens after the increment method completes, I mean I know that the activity restarts, but what method or code comes after it, if any?

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque just disabling the button for a few seconds using a `Handler`.

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque A step towards victory! After hours of commenting and debugging, I found out it happens due to this line being found (It goes away when I comment it):              `mutableData.child("count").setValue(newTotalCount);`

Comment: As your question is put right now, I fear it offers little value to the community (and yourself, as you are trying to solve it for a fairly long time). You are guessing the cause of the issue (a guess which changed several times), and only provide a snippet relevant to the guess. You code appears to have changed multiple times, but it is not available anywhere due to time-limited share (deleted after a week). I suggest you to create a **minimal** reproduction, that will help both you and the community get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @MasterAM I agree, and that's why I edited my post. This is the final code, and I'm sure of that since I know the specific problem

Comment: I would not call that a reproduction. If I were you, I would try to create a very basic activity that demonstrates the issue, with the least amount of external dependencies (if FireBase is a must, so be it), preferably as a GitHub repo. With the provided code, I have no trivial way of creating the code that demonstrates the described behavior, so even seeing what is the problem in a meaningful way takes a certain amount of time and is not guaranteed to be the one you are facing. It will also allow you to eliminate other factors and find things you may have missed.

Comment: @MasterAM sure.

Comment: @MasterAM I am uploading the project to GitHub. I'l give you the link in a sec

Comment: It's not happening in the other project...

Comment: @MasterAM Please check my second edit

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque please check my second edit.

Comment: Interesting observation, but still not that useful without a minimal reproduction that can allow you/us to nail this issue down. Still, if you managed to prevent this issue from happening in your app, this is a good start.

Comment: @MasterAM since the bug seems to only happen in my app, how can I create a minimal reproduction? Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, that is the fine art of bug isolation and reproduction. Not always so easy. Unfortunately, without it it's sometimes fairly difficult to assist or resolve.

Comment: @MasterAM The bug suddenly disappeared AGAIN. Weird

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque ^

Comment: Sorry been busy with an app publish lately. @AbAppletic, Based on the above comments do you still have the problem? what have you modify since the last post update? meanwhile I'm going to keep reading your new findings

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque I did 0 changes. It just suddenly disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will be posting here as its easier to manage my comments)...

**The solution is NOT found.**

<s>*UPDATE 4: Solution Found**</s>

After many tries, and lots of comments, the solution was finally found, apparently the OP had the increment method in another class and moving it to the same class it was being used on solved the issue.

As of why this might happened, in my opinion, maybe it had to do with a concurrency issue on the transaction, maybe the problem was that it was creating a cycle on its own. Your activity starts, later you instantiated your `FirebaseController` which, at some point, fired off the `increment` method, making an async execution which ends up (failing in some way?) and that starts your activity again

**See below for failed  (but troubleshooting steps) attempts**

> I tried to debug. It wasn't activated on any of these lines. It takes
>   me to a bunch of Android files (such as View.java). When I "Run to
>   cursor" (skip the next debug breakpoint), it restarts.

Can you try to check whether the clicked view inside the runnable is not null ?

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // if not null do this
            clicked.setEnabled(true);
            // if null print some log
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Are you using Step Into or Step over when debugging (if you get deeper in the hierarchy of classes you might be using Step Into (F5), can you try debugging with Step Over (F6) )?

If we found the answer I will post it here:

**UPDATE 1:**

`MutableData#setValue(java.lang.Object)`
The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/MutableData#setValue(java.lang.Object)) explains how this works:

> Set the data at this location to the given value. The native types
>   accepted by this method for the value correspond to the JSON types:
>
> `Boolean`
>   `Long`
>   `Double`
>   `Map<String, Object>`
>   `List<Object>`
>
> In addition, you can set instances of your own class into this location, provided they satisfy the following constraints:
>
> The class must have a default constructor that takes no arguments The
>   class must define public getters for the properties to be assigned.
>   Properties without a public getter will be set to their default value
>   when an instance is deserialized

Try using another datatype as suggested by fellow developers:

change the `#setValue` parameter to an object of the list above and [`#getValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/MutableData#getValue()) also return an object, try to cast to the correct type, maybe you could use `Integer` class

**UPDATE 2:**

Does your data schema look something like this?

```
{
    "campaings": {
        "key": {
            "count": "1",
            "users": {
                "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
                    "count": "1",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            }
            ...
        },
        "other-key": {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Thats what I infer from the pieces of code there, you can clarify me if I made  a mistake.

```
// here we are searching for the current reference in Campaings/key
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Campaigns").child(key);

int preIncrementUserCount = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
final int incrementedUserCount = ++preIncrementUserCount;

button.setText(String.valueOf(incrementedUserCount));
database.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {

        // here we are searching for the current count value in 
        // Campaings/key/count
        Integer currentValue = mutableData.child("count").getValue(Integer.class);

        if (currentValue == null) {
            // do something...
        } else {
            // here we are setting the count value in Campaings/key/count
            mutableData.child("count").setValue(++currentValue);
        }

        // here we are setting the count value in Campaings/key/users/UUID/count
        mutableData.child("users").child(getUid()).child("count").setValue(incrementedUserCount);

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       if (databaseError != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
       }

       System.out.println("Transaction completed");
    }
});
```

The point of the code example is to illustrate the data schema searches you are doing *(again, correct me in any part if I made a mistake)*, but please put the `databaseError` log on `onComplete` for debugging purposes

**UPDATE 3**

From the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions):

> doTransaction() will be called multiple times and must be able to
>   handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your remote
>   database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction function
>   is run.

Try changing this part:

```
  if (currentValue == null) {
      // do something...
  } else {
      // here we are setting the count value in Campaings/key/count
      mutableData.child("count").setValue(++currentValue);
  }
```

To something like:

```
  if (mutableData.child("count").getValue() == null) {
      // print something...
      // Log.d(TAG,"Value at some point was null");
      // or maybe (just to test)
      // mutableData.child("count").setValue(1);
  } else {
      // here we are setting the count value in Campaings/key/count
      mutableData.child("count").setValue(++currentValue);
  }
```

**P.S: I'm leaving the solutions if any person in the foreseable future might be troubleshooting something similar like this**

Comment: Anyways, no, `clicked` isn't null

Comment: A step towards victory! After hours of commenting and debugging, I found out it happens due to this line being found (It goes away when I comment it):              `mutableData.child("count").setValue(newTotalCount);`

Comment: Excuse me, I'd like to know if you simply didn't read my comment or didn't find a solution. I'm eager to find a solution

Comment: The bounty is expiring in 22 hours. I'd like to hurry this up so someone can get the award.

Comment: @AbAppletic check the answer's update and the other developers's suggestions

Comment: @AbAppletic can you check the update #2 and let me know if that helped you?

Comment: What you provided me still doesn't work, and `databaseError` is null.

Comment: And you are correct in your statements. I'd like to thank you for hanging on and not giving up on me :)

Comment: No problem @AbAppletic! I told you before we were going to get to the bottom of this :) . question: Do it still saves the data successfully?

Comment: @AbAppletic did you try the update #4? does it print something or the case described does not occur in your case?

Comment: You won't believe how much I appreciate your help. I found the problem (which is actually weird): I had the `increment` method in a different class (`FirebaseController.java`). Moving it to my own class fixed the problem. Can you post another answer, saying what I did, and if you can, explain why, so I can upvote and accept the answer and give you rep? Even if you didn't find the answer, you deserve it. And what would add is a hypothesis why this happens. :)

Comment: @AbAppletic excelent!! Thats great news, now you can keep working in your app in peace :) ... Indeed it seems looks like a very weird bug, but glad you finally solved it. I will do my best and try to make a premise based on the information you've given me

Comment: I posted my answer; whenever you find info, create a different answer. Your current answer is helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I'm going to cry. The bug is back, all of a sudden. About to release my app and this happens. I even tried a git revert. Didn't work...  What the hell is going on?

Comment: I'll check your answer if you solve it. Since the problem is back, I've unchecked it to prevent users from not answering anymore. :)

Comment: Please check out the new edit; I'm sure it will hint you to something

Answer (score 1):

It restarts your activity because it crashes somewhere. Try this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp == null){
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
    } else {
        mp.reset();
    }
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        afd = getAssets().openFd("click.mp3");
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
    } catch (IOException e){
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    v.setEnabled(false);
    final View clicked = v;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            clicked.setEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    handler.postAtTime(runnable,System.currentTimeMillis()+100);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,100);

}
```

Comment: May you explain what difference this makes?

Comment: And when I remove all the `MediaPlayer`  things, the problem persists.

Comment: Weird, that solves it. However, when I call on a method (increment), it also restarts. I'll edit my question

Comment: Please pass the new code with the fix so we can keep troubleshooting :)

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque I knew that and I edited my question. :)

Comment: @AbAppletic please put increment method in try catch. There won't be crashed and restarted app in some abnormal case.

Comment: No exception is thrown

Comment: @IvanAlburquerque anything new? This bug is absurd!

Comment: @AbAppletic: Can you debug in the method `increment`?

Comment: @LiemVo I've been trying, but the screen is black while debugging this

Comment: @LiemVo It turns out its not even happening in **my** code. However, it is happening in the increment method; since when I remove it the method from when I'm calling it it doesn't restart. I've rewrote the code twice and still the same error.

Comment: @AbAppletic: How do you call `increment`?

Comment: `increment(button,key,this);`

Comment: @AbAppletic Are you sure button is not null?

Comment: @LiemVo yes, I am.

Comment: @AbAppletic can you post again the full code with any changes you've made recently? we're going to get through the bottom of this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is trying to start unprepared mediaplayer. Start it like this:

```
 mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer p){
            p.start();

       }       
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Take a look at Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/MutableData#setValue(java.lang.Object)) MutableData setValue(..) method it only accepts the following types. But u use int which is primitive type.

- Boolean
- Long
- Double
- Map
- List

So u should change this

```
 int totalCount = mutableData.child("count").getValue(int.class);
```

with

```
 Long totalCount = mutableData.child("count").getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
        mutableData.child("count").setValue(newTotalCount);
```

you are passing an 'int' value by setValue() method. It should be a supported Object by this method.

[As per the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/MutableData.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)),

```
   public void setValue (Object value)

   Set the data at this location to the given value.
   The native types accepted by this method for the value correspond to the JSON types:

   Boolean
   Long
   Double
   Map<String, Object>
   List<Object>
```

You are passing an 'int' value there. So change that value to corresponding Object.

In this line,

```
 int totalCount = mutableData.child("count").getValue(int.class);
```

you are getting value with 'int.class'. It is not a Object. It also should be a Object. Change this. I hope it will help you.